# How do I show the missing months in mongo aggregate as themselves with 0 for value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

As the title says, I want the months missing from the aggregate result to return *BruteAmount* equals to zero.

**Objective**

The objective of this code is the create an array with the month names and another with its BruteAmounts, while being ordered by the current date and showing the past year values aswell, excluding the current month.

**Problem**

The problem Im having is that while everything work as intended, when are no instances of the *$match* pipeline, the month is skipped, and I cant seem to find a way to fix that.
In my attempts to solve this, I considered answers inside the aggregate and in post processing the resulting arrays, both with no success.

Here Im adding the full code, because Im not really sure if what I want can be done inside the aggregate only, as stated.

```
const Order = require('../models/Order');
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) {
        let currentYear = new Date();
        currentYear.setFullYear(currentYear.getFullYear());
        let pastYear = new Date();
        pastYear.setFullYear(pastYear.getFullYear()-1);
        pastYear.setMonth(currentYear.getMonth()+1);
        pastYear.setDate(1);

        try{
            const orderResponse = await Order.aggregate([
                { $match: {
                    order_ordered_on:{
                        $gte: pastYear,
                        $lt: currentYear
                    },
                    order_status: 'Delivered'
                }},
                { $group : { 
                    _id: {year: {$year : '$order_ordered_on'}, month: {$month : '$order_ordered_on'}},
                    bruteTotal: { $sum: "$order_total"},
                    count: {$sum : 1},
                }},
                { $sort : {
                    _id : 1
                }},
                { $project: {  
                    _id: 0,
                    date: "$_id",
                    bruteTotal:1,
                    count: 1
                }
            }
            ]).catch(error => {throw error});

            let labels = orderResponse.map(month =>(monthNames[month.date.month - 1]));
            let bruteAmount = orderResponse.map(value => value.bruteTotal);

            res.json({
                labels, data: bruteAmount
            });
        }
        catch(message){
            res.send({ error: true, message: String(message) })
        }
    }
};
```

Also, its worth mentioning that while the *count* in the *$group* stage is present, is never really used, I just used it for result control and verification.

**What it looks like now**

```
{
    "labels": [
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
        "January"
    ],
    "data": [
            43964,
            52347.97,
            55272.06,
            40023.21,
            91999.06,
            45559.33,
            45190.14,
            54298.52,
            73056.14,
            31517.5,
            31453.56
    ]
}
```

**What I want**

```
{
    "labels": [
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
        "January",
        "February",
    ],
    "data": [
            43964,
            52347.97,
            55272.06,
            40023.21,
            91999.06,
            45559.33,
            45190.14,
            54298.52,
            73056.14,
            31517.5,
            31453.56,
            0
    ]
}
```

Or if by any chance any past month doesnt have a sale, lets assumo past May:

```
{
    "labels": [
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
        "January",
        "February",
    ],
    "data": [
            43964,
            52347.97,
            0,
            40023.21,
            91999.06,
            45559.33,
            45190.14,
            54298.52,
            73056.14,
            31517.5,
            31453.56,
            0
    ]
}
```

**Also, the raw mongo response (orderResponse) looks like this:***

```
{
    "orderResponse": [
        {
            "bruteTotal": 43964,
            "count": 108,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 52347.97,
            "count": 137,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 55272.06,
            "count": 150,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 40023.21,
            "count": 119,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 91999.06,
            "count": 142,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 45559.33,
            "count": 151,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 45190.14,
            "count": 122,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 9
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 54298.52,
            "count": 146,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 73056.14,
            "count": 166,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 31517.5,
            "count": 64,
            "date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 12
            }
        },
        {
            "bruteTotal": 31453.56,
            "count": 74,
            "date": {
                "year": 2020,
                "month": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post and example of what the return obj looks like now and what you would like?

Comment: @MindlessRouse add it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have a couple of options.  I'm not an aggregate expert so I won't comment on how to get it out of that in the order you want.

Update your data to something a little easier to deal with.  If you dont have to have it as two arrays (remember you can always use Object.keys() to get an array) you can use the spread operator

2 maps isnt efficient anyways.  Lets try this:

```
resData = {  
  0: {label: 'jan', data: 0},
  1: {label: 'feb', data: 0}
  2: {label: 'mar', data: 0}
  // so on
  11: {label: 'dec', data: 0}
}
let labels = orderResponse.forEach(e => {

  resData[e.date.month] = {
    label: monthNames[e.date.month - 1],
    data: e.bruteTotal
  }
});
```

This will look like an array `resData[1]` gets you the label and data for jan.

Its not in the order based on the current month.  However that is something the UI could easily handle by getting the current month and starting the loop there.  Just dont forget to stop at 11 and circle back to 0.

This is a much more typical data object returned to a UI with the label next to the data.  Hopefully this will work.

---

Sometimes easy isnt what you need.  I think this can be done as two arrays. its just a lot trickier and I think it will have a bunch of edgecase bugs.

After your maps, you have to loop over them again, something like this

```
labels.forEach((l, i) => {
  let monthIndex = monthNames.indexOf(l);
  if (labels[i+1] !== monthNames[monthIndex+1]) {
    labels.splice(i+1, 0, monthNames[monthIndex+1]);
    bruteAmount.splice(i+1, 0, 0);
  }
});
```

Putting that after your maps *might* work but it will need some testing and likely some edgecase work.  What happens if you are missing the 1st one or the last one.   I dunno I didnt test it at all

Comment: My bad, I added it to the original post

Comment: I updated it.  two options.  I really really suggest the 1st one

Comment: I need it as two arrays, so I had to go with the second way, and as for sorting it, I asked the front-end developer to do it while I send an 0-11 month array instead of doing it directly with aggregate, which was causing edgecase bugs, as you predicted.